# My brother did too or my brother too

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, grammaticality, sentence-structure

Suppose my friend tells me " My brother went to school" and I also want to tell him " My brother also went to school " , what would be my answer in *short* ?

1. My brother did too.
2. My brother too.

I have seen the first one being used. Is the second one correct to say in shortcut?

Comment: _So did mine_ would be much more idiomatic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of the options you listed, 1. makes more sense than 2., which may confuse the listener. Given the context, though, they'd still probably know what you meant.

I agree with Kate Bunting in the comments though; other options such as "So did mine," or "mine did, too" would be better.

Comment: So for this sentence it would be better to use a helping verb . Let's take another sentence. " I'm inviting you and also your friend". Can I rewrite the sentence as "I'm inviting you and your friend too" ?

Comment: Yep, that second sentence is acceptable! You could remove the "too" as well: "I'm inviting you and your friend" is more commonly said.

Comment: Ok. Now, you said the sentence "My brother too" may confuse the listener. How does it confuse ? Could you please give an example of a sentence that the listener,being confused, may take after listening to this sentence .

Comment: I suppose it wouldn't confuse them too much considering the context of what they said previously, but the other options (like "mine did, too") are more explicit in what it is that your brother did. Worst is they'd just say something like "huh?" as if they didn't quite hear you or something. It's probably not hugely important.